# Join of many to many tables

Tags: mysql, sql

I have 3 tables News, News_tag and Tag, News_tag many to many  relationship between news and Tag. I want make sql query to get all tags with corresponding news count. Please help.

Comment: I want to now with a tag how many news associated.

Comment: Nerses Please do not forget to accept answers which helps you !

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
SELECT COUNT(*) as news_count, t.*
FROM Tag t
    LEFT OUTER JOIN News_Tag nt
        ON t.id = nt.tag_id
GROUP BY t.id
```

Don't forget the outer join to have the tag with 0 news.

Answer (score 2):

I need to know the coloumns to tell you the exact syntax however it will look something like;

```
SELECT TagName, COUNT(*)
FROM Tag t
INNER JOIN NEws_tag tn
   ON t.TagID = tn.TagID
INNER JOIN News n
   ON n.NewsID = tn.NewsID
GROUP BY TagName
```

Look here for deatails of the syntax http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/join.html

Comment: I think you meant n.NewsID = tn.NewsID

Answer (score 1):

Without knowing the structures of the tables, it's difficult to give an answer. You probably want something like this

```
select news.subject, tag.subject
from news, news_tag, tag
where news.id = news_tag.news
and news_tag.tag = tag.id
order by tag.subject
```

Comment: @Scorpi0: To me, downvoting implicit joins seems more evil then the joins themselves. Well, too harsh, anyway, since the solution is **working**.

Comment: This probably should be downvoted... there are many ways to do tagging and to search by tags, some are fast, some are not. Sure it doesn't matter with hundreds or records but it won't scale well

Comment: @Scopi0: what's so evil about implicit joins? Anyway, I was only suggesting a possible solution, without knowing the table structure and without knowing exactly what the OP wanted.

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT COUNT(*)  
FROM news AS n 
LEFT JOIN (news_tag AS nt, tag AS t) 
ON ( 
    nt.tag_id = t.tag_id 
    AND 
    nt.news_id = n.id
)
WHERE (
    t.tag
    IN (
        '$tag'
    )
)
```

Comment: `I want make sql query to get all tags with corresponding news count` you got the count, but not the news tags.

Comment: His answer was hard for me to read, I read it as that he wants the number of news given a tag. I would rewrite it but Scorpi0's answer is already great.

Answer (score 0):

Assuming there's a column named `tag` in both `Tag` and `News_tag`, and that you're looking for the number of `News` items for each `Tag`:

```
SELECT Tag.tag, COUNT(*)
FROM Tag
INNER JOIN News_tag ON News_tag.tag = Tag.Tag
GROUP BY Tag.tag
```